# Native ads in Recyclerview coming randomly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, admob, ads, native-ads

> I want ads after every 9 position & also not after first position
> (which coming automatically at first position)

In **customerAdapter class** -
**onBindViewHolder method**

```
if ((position%9 == 0) and  (position > 0)) {
            MobileAds.initialize(context)
            //build ad
            val adLoader = AdLoader.Builder(context, "ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/yyyyyyyyy")
                .forNativeAd {
                    val style = NativeTemplateStyle.Builder().withMainBackgroundColor(
                        ColorDrawable(
                            Color.WHITE
                        )
                    )
                        .build()
                    //    val template = findViewById<TemplateView>(R.id.my_template)
//                template.setStyles(style)
//                template.setNativeAd(it)

                    holder.templateView.setStyles(style)
                    holder.templateView.setNativeAd(it)
                }.build()
            //show ad
            adLoader.loadAd(AdRequest.Builder().build())
            holder.templateView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        }
```

In **ViewHolder class** -
added this variable

> val templateView : TemplateView =
> itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_template)

Native ads are loading randomly at any position. Not getting any Idea why it is not following my condition given. Please help to check & let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Are you handling the case where the position *shouldn't* show an ad? If the ``ViewHolder`` you're given was used to display an ad before, you need to clear/hide that stuff in ``onBindViewHolder``, otherwise it will still show it

Answer (score 0):

> Added the else part & it working fine now.

```
 else{
            holder.templateView.visibility = View.GONE
        }
```